# Django ManyToMany filtering by set size or member in the set

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am using `django` to maintain a database of messages.
Among others I have the following *models*:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Message(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

I am trying to write a utility method that for a given user gives me the messages he (and he alone) is associated with.

i.e. for:

```
m1 = Message(id=1, body='Some body')
m1.save()
m2 = Message(id=2, body='Another body')
m2.save()
m3 = Message(id=3, body='And yet another body')
m3.save()

u1 = User(name='Jesse James')
u1.save()
u2 = User(name='John Doe')
u2.save()

m1.users.add(u1, u2)
m2.users.add(u1)
m3.users.add(u2)

getMessagesFor('Jesse James')
```

Will return only `m2`.
Assuming I have in `user` the right model instance, it boils down to one line, and I have tried these following:

```
    user.message_set.annotate(usr_cnt=Count('users')).filter(usr_cnt__lte=1)
```

Or:

```
    messages = Message.objects.filter(users__id__in=[user.id])
```

And:

```
    messages = Message.objects.filter(users__id__exact=user.id)
```

And:

```
    messages = Message.objects.filter(users__contains=user)
```

And so on... I always get both `m2` **AND** `m1`.
Tried annotations, excludes, filters etc.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: please check my answer, it should do what you are looking for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
qs = Message.objects.annotate(cc=Count('users')).filter(cc=1)
```

Above query will return all messages which has only single user associated with it.

To filter by user, add another filter at end to filter the annotated query according to user:

```
qs = Message.objects.annotate(cc=Count('users')).filter(cc=1).filter(users__id=user.id)
# if user user.id=1, this will return only m2
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick, I do not understand though why the double filtering does what a single (and more intuitive) one does not.
My first comment was on the initial answer, in the meantime you edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe? (not tested)

```
for msg in Messages.objects.all():
    if (user in msg.users_set.all() and len(msg.users_set.all()) == 1):
        # do something
```