# Django Filter ManyToManyField Queryset

Tags: django, filter, many-to-many

I have a little tricky question (I think)

I have a model called Post(models.Model): with a many to many relation called shares

```
class Post(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name="account")
    shares = models.ManyToManyField(Account, related_name="shares_account", through='Share')
    ...

class Share(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)

    new = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ...
```

Now I need a way to filter Posts which has exact "x" shares .. eg. I have a post with id "222" this post is shared with account id 12, 13, 16 .. now I want to filter on all post shared with account id 12,13 and 16 .

How can I do so?
My bad try is like so:: ;)

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(reduce(and_, [Q(shares=aid) for aid in account_ids]))
```

Comment: You need those posts which are shared with 'x' number of accounts (i.e., the count is equal to x) or do you want those posts which are specifically shared with accounts which include account ids 12, 13 and 16 only or 12,13,16 and more also, but must have 12,13 and 16 in it.?

Comment: Oh .. sorry ... ONLY the accounts with 12,3 and 16 .., if there is more, it will be an other group .. .. so always the exact some shares

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this should work for you.

```
   Post.objects.annotate(cc=Count('shares')).filter(cc=3).filter(Q(shares__id=12) & Q(shares__id=13) & Q(shares__id=16))
```

See this -> [Django ManyToMany filtering by set size or member in the set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067311/django-manytomany-filtering-by-set-size-or-member-in-the-set)

Comment: Can't get it to work .. here is the simple version ..
>>> Post.objects.filter(Q(shares__id=13) & Q(shares__id=12))
[]

>>> [s.id for s in Post.objects.get(id=2308).shares.all()]
[13, 12]

Comment: returns [] ... but if i call a post with shares 12,13 .. then it shows a list with the ids

Comment: But i suppose if you don't include the count filter then your result will contain those Posts which will be shared with account ids 12, 13, 16 and more also as you query is filtering those POSTS which are shared with 12,13 and 16. Nowhere does it filters out those Posts which have exactly these three accounts and no more.

Comment: I mean obviously you can get the list of all Posts being shared with 12,13 and 16 and then loop over them and then store only those who are shared with exactly three accounts in another list, but its not the most efficient way of doing what you want to achieve.

Comment: Shouldn't OP be looking for share IDs that are 12, 13, _or_ 16? Why would a single object have 3 different IDs?

Comment: I am open for a better solution ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is how to achieve it with `reduce`

```
post_qs = Post.objects.all()
post_qs = reduce(lambda posts, share: posts.filter(shares=share), account_ids, post_qs)
```

Which I would probably make it more reusable this way:

```
class PostQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def having_shares(self, share_ids):
        return reduce(lambda posts, share: posts.filter(shares=share), share_ids, self)

class Post(models.Model):
    ...

    objects = PostQuerySet.as_manager(


#usage
posts = Post.objects.all().having_shares(share_ids)
```